# How do I convert a variable into the gotten type of another variable?

Tags: c#

Edit: Ok here's a longer explanation of what i'm doing:

Here's an ordered dictionary labled "Storage"...

```
public OrderedDictionary Storage = new OrderedDictionary()
    {
                { "Trinkets", new List<Trinket>{} },
                { "Misc Equipment", new List<MiscEquipment>{} },
                { "Headdresses", new List<Headdress>{} },
                { "Weapons", new List<Weapon>{} },
                //and so on...
    };
```

of which "AddToStorage()" is meant to take a parameter (item) that is any of the list value types featured in Storage without needing to test for every potential type with a number of "else if"s.

So here's what i'm trying to do but I get the error of "'ItemType' is a variable but is used like a type":

```
public void AddToStorage(object item)
{    
        int index=0;
        foreach (object storageList in Storage)
        {
            if (storageList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == item.GetType())
            {
                Type ItemType = item.GetType();
                //here's where the problem is 
                (Storage[index] as List<ItemType>).Add(item as ItemType);
            }
        index++;
        }
}
```

### So I apparently cant use the variable of the Type "Type" "like a type" because the variable of the Type "Type" is a variable not a type. rip.

Comment: can you have multiple overloads for `AddToStorage` that take each expected type?

Comment: Yeah this is never going to work, what are you trying to do fundamentally so we can point you in the right direction , update your question

Comment: Why don't you try writing your AddStorage method in a generic way like `public void AddToStorage<T>(T item)`. This way you can use `T` instead of messing around with your ItemType variable (**Attention!** T will be infered from the type of the reference/variable that will be passed to such a method, not from the type of the object itself)

Comment: Yeah I'll probably end up doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trinket`, `MiscEquipment`, `Headdress`, and `Weapon` sound like they should all derive from a common `Item` type (or implement a common `IItem` interface).

For arguments' sake, let's say they all derive from `Item`. You could modify your method to accept a constrained generic:

```
public void AddToStorage<TItem>(TItem item)
    where TItem: Item, new()
{    
    var storageList = Storage.Values.OfType<List<TItem>>().Single();
    storageList.Add(item);
}
```

Using the constrained generic (constrained by `where TItem: Item`), you can find a List of type `List<TITem>` and add your item to it. The `new()` part will ensure that the type as a public parameterless constructor (and thus not abstract or an interface).

Note that `.Single()` expects that exactly one list of type `List<TItem>` is found, and will throw an exception if this is not the case. You could change this to `SingleOrDefault()`, and add a null check, if there's a possibility that the list might not exist. From what I understand of your scenario, this won't be the case so `.Single()` should be OK.

Comment: Some additional notes: if you do something like: `Item x = new Trinket(); ... AddToStorage(x);` the method here will look for a `List<Item>` and not for a `List<Trinket>`. If `Item` is an abstract class or interface (which it preferably should be), TItem should be further constrained to allow only concrete (instantiable) types, preventing the scenario i outlined here.

Comment: So I have another thing I did not mention in the question for the sake of simplicity but there is a variation of list that consists of tuples instead of a direct item (where item1 is the type and item2 is the amount (this is for items that stack with each-other since they won't ever have a unique value within their instance) i.e. "List<tuple<Consumables,100>>") and instead of adding to the list a new object; rather there's a function that looks for the same type (if already added) and "increments" item 2 in the tuple. Would i make another "where" case somehow?

Comment: @DED It might be worth adding another method for that. Although you can have a where for each generic parameter, it doesn't sound like this is your use case. For a better general solution, I'd be tempted to consider a single item as a stack of 1 rather than trying to manage to diverging ways of storing very similar information.